# Accessing members in a superclass from a base class

Tags: android, kotlin

Here's an example of inheritance in Kotlin:

```kotlin
abstract class Animal(val size: Int)
class Dog(val cuteness: Int): Animal(345)

var dog: Dog = Dog(10)
var animal: Animal = dog

var x = 0
...
```

If you put a breakpoint on the last line, the variable `animal` will be set to the instance of `dog`. However, you can only access the `size` member in Animal. You can't access the `cuteness` member in Dog. But Android Studio's debugger still lets you see the value of the cuteness member in the `animal` variable.

Is there a way in code to access those hidden members? I don't think there is. I think that Android Studio knows what they are and shows them to you for debugging purposes, but because they are not accessible through Kotlin, it will prevent you from actually accessing them in code. Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question is answered but I want to say some additional informations.

Well when you declare animal variable you set its type to `Animal`, so animal can't be anything else, and if you assign to it a type that inherits from `Animal` like `Dog`, the `Dog` is going to be casted to an `Animal` and that's what happening in your case so you have access to animal members only.

But you are able to cast that `Animal` back to it's original type which is `Dog` using `as`:

```
(animal as Dog).cuteness
```

But be careful if the `Animal` is not a `Dog` your program will crash, so you can use safe cast with `as?` which is going to return a nullable `Dog?`, if something goes wrong it's going to return `null` instead of throwing an exception:

```
val safeDog: Dog? = (animal as? Dog)
safeDog?.cuteness
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use casting :

Cast the animal(object) to Dog Type and you can access cuteness
the field  you can also change its value   if you desire

```
  val dog: Dog = Dog(10)
  val animal: Animal = dog

  println(animal.size)
  println((animal as Dog).cuteness)
```

I admit this is not the best solution but it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You want access the cuteness of the animal. You must using for that.

```
(animal as Dog).cuteness
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but would it throw all the things that inheritance offers if the parent type has access to its child **only specific** properties?

The only way I can think of is the `Animal` have an open property `cuteness` that can be inherited by its children

```
abstract class Animal(val size: Int, open val cuteness: Int)

class Dog(override val cuteness: Int): Animal(345, cuteness)
```

this way, `Dog` instance or any instance declared as `Animal` type can call the `cuteness` like the way you want it to

```
animal.cuteness
```

or simply like the other answer, just casting it back to `Dog` type